# How to div scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div class="btn-toggle">
<div class="description ">
<div class="Area" style="height: auto; visibility: visible; overflow: hidden;">
<div class="scrollbar" style="height: 340px;">
<div class="watch" style="height: 340px;">
<div class="round" style="height: 100px; top: 0px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

While running selenium code, need to scroll to the bottom of the div. How do update "style =height: 100px; top: 100px;".

How to accomplish this using Javascript?

Comment: you want to goto the bottom of the page?

Comment: You question isn't 100% clear. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I working on Safari browser,On expanding a button, list of items are displayed along with the scrollbar. I need to scroll to the end of this expanded list where in I need to perform some action on the button.

Comment: Using javascript can we dynamically update the style property? manually updating Top= 100px works. I need to find a way to do this using javascript

Comment: I updated fiddle. is this u want?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there was little confusion ,but not not now. check out fiddle .See style properly.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rp44L/1/)

Use the following code , say you want to scroll to bottom of "round" div,

```
var scr = $('#box')[0].scrollHeight;
$('#box').animate({scrollTop: scr},2000);
```

CSS :

```
#box{
  overflow:auto;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
}
```

Say HTML is

```
<div id="box">


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam non tellus nisi, at euismod lacus. Praesent elementum, purus vitae imperdiet bibendum, erat nisl congue libero, vitae bibendum diam quam sed orci. Integer magna justo, dapibus et sagittis et, porta sit amet augue. Ut sed felis et odio egestas sodales eget vel sapien. Vivamus laoreet fermentum odio, eu fringilla nisi pulvinar at. Cras quis mauris erat, et varius massa. Aenean sit amet consequat purus. Aenean at lectus sem.

Donec lobortis pulvinar ornare. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae turpis massa, quis vehicula mauris. Fusce in ante libero. Aliquam consectetur suscipit dui eu vestibulum. Aenean felis purus, volutpat et sollicitudin at, feugiat non odio. Sed feugiat, augue non volutpat congue, ipsum magna vehicula dolor, non ornare mi mauris nec ipsum. Integer sed odio eget nisl posuere porttitor vitae suscipit lectus. Cras vehicula, justo nec ornare rhoncus, enim urna euismod justo, quis scelerisque metus dolor at leo.

Maecenas non elit sapien. Proin fringilla pellentesque ultrices. Proin rhoncus eleifend nisl, nec consequat dui porta id. Aliquam ut erat libero. Integer at tristique est. Duis iaculis, augue vel tempus congue, elit mi pellentesque felis, ut interdum risus tortor vitae nulla. Praesent malesuada mattis fermentum. Donec luctus pharetra nem, erat nisl congue libero, vitae bibendum diam quam sed orci. Integer magna justo, dapibus et sagittis et, porta sit amet augue. Ut sed felis et odio egestas sodales eget vel sapien. Vivamus laoreet fermentum odio, eu fringilla nisi pulvinar at. Cras quis mauris erat, et varius massa. Aenean sit amet consequat purus. Aenean at lectus sem.

Donec lobortis pulvinar ornare. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae turpis massa, quis vehicula mauris. Fusce in ante libero. Aliquam consectetur suscipit dui eu vestibulum. Aenean felis purus, volutpat et sollicitudin at, feugiat non odio. Sed feugiat, augue non volutpat congue, ipsum magna vehicula dolor, non ornare mi mauris nec ipsum. Integer sed odio eget nisl posuere porttitor vitae suscipit lectus. Cras vehicula, justo nec ornare rhoncus, enim urna euismod justo, quis scelerisque metus dolor at leo.

Maecenas non elit sapien. Proin fringilla pellentesque ultrices. Proin rhoncus eleifend nisl, nec consequat dui porta id. Aliquam ut erat libero. Integer at tristique est. Duis iaculis, augue vel tempus congue, elit mi pellentesque felis, ut interdum risus tortor vitae nulla. Praesent malesuada mattis fermentum. Donec luctus pharetra nem, erat nisl congue libero, vitae bibendum diam quam sed orci. Integer magna justo, dapibus et sagittis et, porta sit amet augue. Ut sed felis et odio egestas sodales eget vel sapien. Vivamus laoreet fermentum odio, eu fringilla nisi pulvinar at. Cras quis mauris erat, et varius massa. Aenean sit amet consequat purus. Aenean at lectus sem.

Donec lobortis pulvinar ornare. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae turpis massa, quis vehicula mauris. Fusce in ante libero. Aliquam consectetur suscipit dui eu vestibulum. Aenean felis purus, volutpat et sollicitudin at, feugiat non odio. Sed feugiat, augue non volutpat congue, ipsum magna vehicula dolor, non ornare mi mauris nec ipsum. Integer sed odio eget nisl posuere porttitor vitae suscipit lectus. Cras vehicula, justo nec ornare rhoncus, enim urna euismod justo, quis scelerisque metus dolor at leo.

Maecenas non elit sapien. Proin fringilla pellentesque ultrices. Proin rhoncus eleifend nisl, nec consequat dui porta id. Aliquam ut erat libero. Integer at tristique est. Duis iaculis, augue vel tempus congue, elit mi pellentesque felis, ut interdum risus tortor vitae nulla. Praesent malesuada mattis fermentum. Donec luctus pharetra nem, erat nisl congue libero, vitae bibendum diam quam sed orci. Integer magna justo, dapibus et sagittis et, porta sit amet augue. Ut sed felis et odio egestas sodales eget vel sapien. Vivamus laoreet fermentum odio, eu fringilla nisi pulvinar at. Cras quis mauris erat, et varius massa. Aenean sit amet consequat purus. Aenean at lectus sem.

Donec lobortis pulvinar ornare. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae turpis massa, quis vehicula mauris. Fusce in ante libero. Aliquam consectetur suscipit dui eu vestibulum. Aenean felis purus, volutpat et sollicitudin at, feugiat non odio. Sed feugiat, augue non volutpat congue, ipsum magna vehicula dolor, non ornare mi mauris nec ipsum. Integer sed odio eget nisl posuere porttitor vitae suscipit lectus. Cras vehicula, justo nec ornare rhoncus, enim urna euismod justo, quis scelerisque metus dolor at leo.

Maecenas non elit sapien. Proin fringilla pellentesque ultrices. Proin rhoncus eleifend nisl, nec consequat dui porta id. Aliquam ut erat libero. Integer at tristique est. Duis iaculis, augue vel tempus congue, elit mi pellentesque felis, ut interdum risus tortor vitae nulla. Praesent malesuada mattis fermentum. Donec luctus pharetra nem, erat nisl congue libero, vitae bibendum diam quam sed orci. Integer magna justo, dapibus et sagittis et, porta sit amet augue. Ut sed felis et odio egestas sodales eget vel sapien. Vivamus laoreet fermentum odio, eu fringilla nisi pulvinar at. Cras quis mauris erat, et varius massa. Aenean sit amet consequat purus. Aenean at lectus sem.

Donec lobortis pulvinar ornare. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae turpis massa, quis vehicula mauris. Fusce in ante libero. Aliquam consectetur suscipit dui eu vestibulum. Aenean felis purus, volutpat et sollicitudin at, feugiat non odio. Sed feugiat, augue non volutpat congue, ipsum magna vehicula dolor, non ornare mi mauris nec ipsum. Integer sed odio eget nisl posuere porttitor vitae suscipit lectus. Cras vehicula, justo nec ornare rhoncus, enim urna euismod justo, quis scelerisque metus dolor at leo.

Maecenas non elit sapien. Proin fringilla pellentesque ultrices. Proin rhoncus eleifend nisl, nec consequat dui porta id. Aliquam ut erat libero. Integer at tristique est. Duis iaculis, augue vel tempus congue, elit mi pellentesque felis, ut interdum risus tortor vitae nulla. Praesent malesuada mattis fermentum. Donec luctus pharetra neque, non dignissim sem condimentum vitae. Quisque varius nibh nec felis facilisis nec consectetur augue ultrices.

Nullam ut arcu nisi, eu volutpat neque. Etiam lobortis, erat vel mollis aliquam, sapien eros bibendum erat, vel mollis purus neque sit amet quam. Proin semper aliquet leo. Morbi erat ipsum, vehicula eget mattis sed, venenatis in lectus. Cras quis dui nunc. Vestibulum viverra tempus nisl pulvinar tempor. Donec vitae nunc quam, eu placerat nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla ante dolor, varius eget porttitor eu, malesuada vel nisl. Vestibulum in justo eros. Maecenas id lorem metus, et auctor nibh. Maecenas ut porttitor felis.

Praesent blandit elementum fringilla. Curabitur tincidunt, libero in convallis volutpat, enim purus sodales lacus, vel euismod ante erat nec est. Nam non metus quis lorem ornare dictum sit amet et mauris. Curabitur molestie porta tortor vel adipiscing. Pellentesque sed nulla vel neque tempor sodales. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam nisl mauris, faucibus at blandit mollis, malesuada eu risus. Nunc urna lacus, egestas et euismod non, vehicula sed ligula. 
  </div>
```

Comment: Pratik, i tried executing this in console and it didn't work.